# Marinate pork loin overnight?

Tags: pork

I'm looking at this recipe:
http://www.chow.com/recipes/30370-cuban-rotisserie-pork-loin-with-peppers-and-onions

It says to marinate for 2 hours. Do you think it would be ok to marinate overnight?
I'm just looking to make less work the day of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my "expert" opinion as a great lover of all things pork, I say yes, that marinade will be fine overnight. It's quite acidic, and that's a concern, but it's not so acidic as to create mush. You'll be fine marinating overnight. As a matter of fact, I'm surprised that the recipe doesn't say "2 hours up to overnight".

Comment: Thanks. I marinated it overnight and it was delicious. Sorry I can't upvote yet.